# Proof verification of continuity of $f$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

**Question:** Let $f:\mathbb{R^2} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a function such that:

**(I)** For all $y_0 \in \mathbb{R}$, $f(x,y_0)$ is continuous.

**(II)** For all $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}$, $f(x_0, y)$ is continuous.

**(III)** If $K\subset\mathbb{R^2}$ is compact, then $f(K)$ is compact.

Show that $f$ is continuous.

**My attempt was:** We shall prove that $\lim f(z_n) = f(\lim z_n)$. Take $(x_n,y_n) \in \mathbb{R^2}$ such that $(x_n,y_n) \to (x,y)$. Since $(x_n,y_n)$ is bounded, exists $K \subset \mathbb{R^2}$ compact such that $(x_n,y_n) \subset K$ and, by **(III)**, $f(x_n,y_n)$ is bounded. By *Bolzano-Weierstrass* exists a subsequence convergent. Take any convergent subsequence $f(x_{n_k}, y_{n_k}) \to f(x',y')$. Note that $f(x',y') = \lim f(x_{n_k}, y')$, and, by **(I)**, $\lim f(x_{n_k}, y') = f(x,y')$. Same argument using **(II)** for $y'$. Therefore $f(x',y') = f(x,y)$. Hence, since every convergent subsequence of $f(x_n,y_n)$ converge to $f(x,y)$, $\lim f(x_n,y_n) = f(x,y)$, that is, $f$ is continuous. $\blacksquare$

Is that right?

Comment: You can use QED in place of the black square :-)

Comment: Thanks ^^ Here in Brazil we use "CQD", it's good to know other versions :p

Comment: why is $f(x',y') = \lim f(x_{n_k},y')$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Several comments:

1. It is not enough to say that $f(x_n,y_n)$ is bounded and hence it has a convergent subsequence because then you would have to write $f(x_{n_k},y_{n_k}) \rightarrow L$ and you wouldn't a priori know that $L$ has the form $L = f(x',y')$ for some $(x',y') \in \mathbb{R}^2$ like you assume in the proof. In the way your argument is written, nothing precludes the sequence to converge to a limit outside the image of $f$. However, you know something stronger - since $f(K)$ is compact and $f(x_n,y_n) \in f(K)$, there exists a subsequence $f(x_{n_k},y_{n_k})$ that converges to **an element of $f(K)$** and hence the limit is of the form $f(x',y')$ for $(x',y') \in K$.
2. Your "note that $f(x',y') = \lim f(x_{n_k},y')$" needs to be justified as this is the most important point of the proof and you rely on it heavily.
3. In the end, I would write "the argument shows that every subsequence of $f(x_n,y_n)$ has a convergent subsequence that converges to $f(x,y)$ and so..." and not "Hence, since every convergent subsequence..." because, strictly speaking, this is enough (maybe $f(x_n,y_n)$ has subsequences that don't converge?).

Comment: 1. Yes yes, my fault! I forget to say that f(K) is compact. 2. It's sufficient write "f(x',y') = f(lim xnk, y') = lim f(xnk, y')"?. 3 I think that is a English problem, I didn't learn it yet :c thanks!

Comment: Regarding 2, why $f(x',y') = f(\lim_{k \to \infty} x_{n_k}, y')$?

Comment: Well... I used that $\lim x_{n_k} = x'$, but I don't know if that is true. Any hint of how can I proceed to justify that argument?

Comment: Edit: That isn't true